# How to get hex color value rather than RGB value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, hex, rgb

Using the following jQuery will get the RGB value of an element's background color:

```
$('#selector').css('backgroundColor');
```

Is there a way to get the hex value rather than the RGB?

Comment: On a related topic, more (and arguably better) ways to convert between hex and RGB colours are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb This wheel has been reinvented enough times to build a road train. I was hoping one of the popular JS libraries, simpler than less, would have a utility function.

Comment: Remember that some browsers return rgba(#,#,#,#), such as rgba(0,0,0,0) which is transparent, not black. The 4th value is the opacity, with 1.0 being full color 100% and 0.5 being 50%.

Comment: Ideally one would be able to tell the browser what format. I get the impression the people who work with browser are pushing RGBA more than the well loved hex coes.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

```
var hexDigits = new Array
        ("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"); 

//Function to convert rgb color to hex format
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
 rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
 return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}

function hex(x) {
  return isNaN(x) ? "00" : hexDigits[(x - x % 16) / 16] + hexDigits[x % 16];
 }
```

([Source](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2009/06/convert-jquery-rgb-output-to-hex-color.html))

Comment: +1, You could use Number.toString(16) - at least for each hex digit (or pad with 0 if under 16)

Comment: -1. As mentioned by orip, you could use toString(16). Downvoted for other inefficiencies. If you're going to declare hexDigits on every function call, at least do it in rgb2hex's function body (not hex's body), so the array is not redefined 3 times per 1 call to rgb2hex. Also learn to use 'var', so you don't pollute the global scope.

Comment: This method does not seem very tolerant of differing white-space or capitalisation. http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/pSQ7d/

Comment: If you realy want to be pedantic, you can make the regex more permissive:
`rgb.match(/^rgb\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)$/i)`
However, the regex given is designed to cope with the format given by a browser when using jQuery, and this doesn't have the different white-space or captilisation consistencies you are talking about. You could also use the same regex and just remove all whitespaces and convert to lowercase before matching on rgb. P.S. Your fiddle example: 'rgb(10, 128,)' I don't think that is reasonable to test on

Comment: and for me the return of jquery css background-colors comes in format with rgba , so this does not works.

Comment: if you want to support rgba use this expression:
rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(,\s*\d+)?\)$/);

Comment: @SlimFadi your regex doesn't work because you un-escaped the parenthesis. Once that's fixed, it would match invalid values such as rgb(0, 0, 0, 0) and rgba(0, 0 ,0) too, but that shouldn't be a problem for this purpose.

Answer (score 210):

## TL;DR

Use this clean one-line function with both `rgb` and `rgba` support:

```
const rgba2hex = (rgba) => `#${rgba.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+\.{0,1}\d*))?\)$/).slice(1).map((n, i) => (i === 3 ? Math.round(parseFloat(n) * 255) : parseFloat(n)).toString(16).padStart(2, '0').replace('NaN', '')).join('')}`
```

### 2021 updated answer

Much time has passed since I originally answered this question. Then cool ECMAScript 5 and 2015+ features became largely available on browsers, like [arrow functions](https://caniuse.com/arrow-functions), [Array.map](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_array_map), [String.padStart](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_string_padstart) and [template strings](https://caniuse.com/template-literals). Since some years, it's possible to write cross-browser one-liner `rgb2hex`:

```js
const rgb2hex = (rgb) => `#${rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/).slice(1).map(n => parseInt(n, 10).toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('')}`

// Use as you wish...
console.log(rgb2hex('rgb(0,0,0)'))
console.log(rgb2hex('rgb(255, 255, 255)'))
console.log(rgb2hex('rgb(255,0,0)'))
console.log(rgb2hex('rgb(38, 170, 90)'))
```

It works by using a regular expression to get each digit inside the `rgb` string, `slice(1)` to get only the digits (the first result of `match` is the full string itself), `map` to iterate through each digit, each iteration converting to `Number` with `parseInt`, then back to an hexadecimal `String` (through a base-16 conversion), adding zero if needed via `padStart`. Finally, `join` each converted/adjusted digit to a unique `String` starting with `'#'`.

Of course, we could extend it without much effort as an one-liner `rgba2hex`:

```js
const rgba2hex = (rgba) => `#${rgba.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+\.{0,1}\d*))?\)$/).slice(1).map((n, i) => (i === 3 ? Math.round(parseFloat(n) * 255) : parseFloat(n)).toString(16).padStart(2, '0').replace('NaN', '')).join('')}`

// Now it doesn't matter if 'rgb' or 'rgba'...
console.log(rgba2hex('rgb(0,0,0)'))
console.log(rgba2hex('rgb(255, 255, 255)'))
console.log(rgba2hex('rgb(255,0,0)'))
console.log(rgba2hex('rgb(38, 170, 90)'))
console.log(rgba2hex('rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)'))
console.log(rgba2hex('rgba(0,255,0,1)'))
console.log(rgba2hex('rgba(127,127,127,0.25)'))
```

And that's it. But if you want to dive deep in the old school JavaScript world, keep reading.

---

### Original 2010 answer

Here is the cleaner solution I wrote based on @Matt suggestion:

```
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    function hex(x) {
        return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}
```

Some browsers already returns colors as hexadecimal (as of Internet Explorer 8 and below). If you need to deal with those cases, just append a condition inside the function, like @gfrobenius suggested:

```
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    if (/^#[0-9A-F]{6}$/i.test(rgb)) return rgb;

    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    function hex(x) {
        return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}
```

If you're using jQuery and want a more complete approach, you can use [CSS Hooks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/) available since jQuery 1.4.3, as I showed when answering this question: [Can I force jQuery.css("backgroundColor") returns on hexadecimal format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177454/can-i-force-jquery-cssbackgroundcolor-returns-on-hexadecimal-format)

Comment: I suggest to everyone: take a look at my response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177454/can-i-force-jquery-cssbackgroundcolor-returns-on-hexadecimal-format) to see a improved version using [jQuery CSS Hooks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/).

Comment: @Ghigo, sorry but you are wrong. IE8 already returns colors as hexadecimal when getting the current style, this way: `document.getElementById("your_id").currentStyle["backgroundColor"]`. The function `rgb2hex()` isn't needed. Here's the jQuery plugin using CSS Hooks that I suggested above, which already does all the validations to recover colors in different browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177454/can-i-force-jquery-cssbackgroundcolor-returns-on-hexadecimal-format

Comment: I'm not wrong. I don't want to put browser detection here and there to handle different implementations. The solution just below from Jim F handle correctly IE8. Your code do not handle IE8 and its hexadecimal color format, Jim color does. That's all.

Comment: @Ghigo, I think you misunderstand: you SHOULD NOT use this function if you are in a browser that returns in HEX. This function convert RGB to HEX and just it. Do not use it when it's not in RGB. The fact that you need a more complete solution (which detects if the value is already as RGB, as made by @Jim-F) don't change the fact that this solution offers exactly what was requested by the OP. Your downvote makes no sense, sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not agree. A cross browser function is always better than one that need execution based on browser detection. Op asked to convert `$('#selector').css('backgroundColor')` to hex, not a rgb value to hex. And on IE8, `$('#selector').css('backgroundColor')` is already hex so it must be handled. That's it. Don't get mad at me :)

Comment: Do this guys, a simple one liner I added to the `rgb2hex()` function, thanks @ErickPetru! I have to code back to IE7 believe it or not. With `.css('backgroundColor')` and native `obj.style.backgroundColor` IE7 & 8 will return hex, not RGB, so I added this as the first line in the `rgb2hex()` function in the supplied answer so it works all the way back to IE7: `/* IE7&8 will return hex, so no need to run this function if it is already hex. */` `if (/^#[0-9A-F]{6}$/i.test(rgb)) return rgb.substring(1, 7); //I'm doing a subtring here because I do not want the leading # symbol` Hope that helps.

Comment: This is the best answer i think because it accepts the jquery css output directly and returns the hex.

Comment: @Gaurav, for jQuery users I strongly suggest the [approach with CSS Hooks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177454/can-i-force-jquery-cssbackgroundcolor-returns-on-hexadecimal-format).

Comment: Slightly shorter: `rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/).slice(1).map(i => parseInt(i).toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');`

Answer (score 66):

Most browsers seem to return the RGB value when using:

```
$('#selector').css('backgroundColor');
```

Only I.E (only 6 tested so far) returns the Hex value.

To avoid error messages in I.E, you could wrap the function in an if statement:

```
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
     if (  rgb.search("rgb") == -1 ) {
          return rgb;
     } else {
          rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+))?\)$/);
          function hex(x) {
               return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
          }
          return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]); 
     }
}
```

Comment: This one works better than most others, since Jim takes rgba into account, which is what Safari (at least on Mac OS X) uses. Thanks, Jim!

Comment: Great solution. Note that function returns lower case letters i.e. #ff5544 not #FF5544.

Comment: This regex will support aplha channels as well in the above solution
rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(0\.\d+))?\)$/);

Answer (score 24):

Updated @ErickPetru for rgba compatibility:

```
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+))?\)$/);
    function hex(x) {
        return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}
```

I updated the regex to match the alpha value if defined, but not use it.

Comment: Just for completeness: I am working on a thing that will export to PowerPoint (don't ask...), and it accepts a fourth byte on the hex string for the alpha channel, so one can make use of it like this:

`return hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3])
            /* Add the alpha channel if it exists */
            + (rgb[5] !== undefined ? hex(Math.round(rgb[5] * 255)) : '');`

Also I am removing the `#` symbol to make it agnostic of the final use (one could get the output and prepend it with `0x` for example, or leave it without prefix). Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 13):

Here's an ES6 one liner that doesn't use jQuery:

```
var rgb = document.querySelector('#selector').style['background-color'];
return '#' + rgb.substr(4, rgb.indexOf(')') - 4).split(',').map((color) => parseInt(color).toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me incorporate it into a Wordpress page which strips out the regex backslashes in the previous answers.

Comment: This answer does not work for small numbers, e.g. `parseInt('0').toString(16) # => '0'`, the string must be padded if it's a single digit `parseInt('0').toString(16).padStart(2, '0') => '00'`.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a version that also checks for transparent, I needed this since my object was to insert the result into a style attribute, where the transparent version of a hex color is actually the word "transparent"..

```
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
     if (  rgb.search("rgb") == -1 ) {
          return rgb;
     }
     else if ( rgb == 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' ) {
         return 'transparent';
     }
     else {
          rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+))?\)$/);
          function hex(x) {
               return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
          }
          return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]); 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## Short

```
// c - color str e.g."rgb(12,233,43)", result color hex e.g. "#0ce92b"
let rgb2hex=c=>'#'+c.match(/\d+/g).map(x=>(+x).toString(16).padStart(2,0)).join``
```

```js
// rgb - color str e.g."rgb(12,233,43)", result color hex e.g. "#0ce92b"
let rgb2hex= c=> '#'+c.match(/\d+/g).map(x=>(+x).toString(16).padStart(2,0)).join``

console.log(rgb2hex("rgb(12,233,43"));
```

Answer (score 6):

Function that returns background color of an element in hex.

```
function getBgColorHex(elem){
    var color = elem.css('background-color')
    var hex;
    if(color.indexOf('#')>-1){
        //for IE
        hex = color;
    } else {
        var rgb = color.match(/\d+/g);
        hex = '#'+ ('0' + parseInt(rgb[0], 10).toString(16)).slice(-2) + ('0' + parseInt(rgb[1], 10).toString(16)).slice(-2) + ('0' + parseInt(rgb[2], 10).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }
    return hex;
}
```

usage example:

```
$('#div1').click(function(){
   alert(getBgColorHex($(this));
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shabuddin/5fu68pv9/1/)

Answer (score 5):

## Readable && Reg-exp free (no Reg-exp)

I've created a function that uses readable basic functions and no reg-exps.

The function accepts color in hex, rgb **or rgba** CSS format and returns hex representation.

**EDIT:** there was a bug with parsing out rgba() format, fixed...

```
function getHexColor( color ){
    //if color is already in hex, just return it...
    if( color.indexOf('#') != -1 ) return color;
    
    //leave only "R,G,B" :
    color = color
                .replace("rgba", "") //must go BEFORE rgb replace
                .replace("rgb", "")
                .replace("(", "")
                .replace(")", "");
    color = color.split(","); // get Array["R","G","B"]
    
    // 0) add leading #
    // 1) add leading zero, so we get 0XY or 0X
    // 2) append leading zero with parsed out int value of R/G/B
    //    converted to HEX string representation
    // 3) slice out 2 last chars (get last 2 chars) => 
    //    => we get XY from 0XY and 0X stays the same
    return  "#"
            + ( '0' + parseInt(color[0], 10).toString(16) ).slice(-2)
            + ( '0' + parseInt(color[1], 10).toString(16) ).slice(-2)
            + ( '0' + parseInt(color[2], 10).toString(16) ).slice(-2);
}
```

Comment: Does not work on rgba(0,0,0,0).  First: the order needs to change `.replace("rgba", "")
                .replace("rgb", "")
                .replace("(", "")
                .replace(")", "");` Otherwise, you get left with a0,0,0,0. And, it returns #000000, which is Black, instead of transparent.

Comment: If the 4th value in an rgba is 0 (zero), then for css for that 'element' would be: element{ color: #000000, opacity: 0.0;} which is transparent or just conditionally return the 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' back to the caller.

Comment: @Twelve24 Parsing fixed - I actually noticed that before reading your comment, but definitely thanks for that :) , **As for transparency** - function is  supposed to return HEXA color, or the "base color" -  so that one is **on purpose** :)

Answer (score 5):

Same  answer [like @Jim F answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4090628/747579)  but **ES6** syntax , so,  less instructions :

```
const rgb2hex = (rgb) => {
  if (rgb.search("rgb") === -1) return rgb;
  rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+))?\)$/);
  const hex = (x) => ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

color class taken from bootstrap color picker

```
// Color object
var Color = function(val) {
    this.value = {
        h: 1,
        s: 1,
        b: 1,
        a: 1
    };
    this.setColor(val);
};

Color.prototype = {
    constructor: Color,

    //parse a string to HSB
    setColor: function(val){
        val = val.toLowerCase();
        var that = this;
        $.each( CPGlobal.stringParsers, function( i, parser ) {
            var match = parser.re.exec( val ),
            values = match && parser.parse( match ),
            space = parser.space||'rgba';
            if ( values ) {
                if (space === 'hsla') {
                    that.value = CPGlobal.RGBtoHSB.apply(null, CPGlobal.HSLtoRGB.apply(null, values));
                } else {
                    that.value = CPGlobal.RGBtoHSB.apply(null, values);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    },

    setHue: function(h) {
        this.value.h = 1- h;
    },

    setSaturation: function(s) {
        this.value.s = s;
    },

    setLightness: function(b) {
        this.value.b = 1- b;
    },

    setAlpha: function(a) {
        this.value.a = parseInt((1 - a)*100, 10)/100;
    },

    // HSBtoRGB from RaphaelJS
    // https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/
    toRGB: function(h, s, b, a) {
        if (!h) {
            h = this.value.h;
            s = this.value.s;
            b = this.value.b;
        }
        h *= 360;
        var R, G, B, X, C;
        h = (h % 360) / 60;
        C = b * s;
        X = C * (1 - Math.abs(h % 2 - 1));
        R = G = B = b - C;

        h = ~~h;
        R += [C, X, 0, 0, X, C][h];
        G += [X, C, C, X, 0, 0][h];
        B += [0, 0, X, C, C, X][h];
        return {
            r: Math.round(R*255),
            g: Math.round(G*255),
            b: Math.round(B*255),
            a: a||this.value.a
        };
    },

    toHex: function(h, s, b, a){
        var rgb = this.toRGB(h, s, b, a);
        return '#'+((1 << 24) | (parseInt(rgb.r) << 16) | (parseInt(rgb.g) << 8) | parseInt(rgb.b)).toString(16).substr(1);
    },

    toHSL: function(h, s, b, a){
        if (!h) {
            h = this.value.h;
            s = this.value.s;
            b = this.value.b;
        }
        var H = h,
        L = (2 - s) * b,
        S = s * b;
        if (L > 0 && L <= 1) {
            S /= L;
        } else {
            S /= 2 - L;
        }
        L /= 2;
        if (S > 1) {
            S = 1;
        }
        return {
            h: H,
            s: S,
            l: L,
            a: a||this.value.a
        };
    }
};
```

how to use

```
var color = new Color("RGB(0,5,5)");
color.toHex()
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to @Justin's answer above..

it should be

```
var rgb = document.querySelector('#selector').style['background-color'];
return '#' + rgb.substr(4, rgb.indexOf(')') - 4).split(',').map((color) => String("0" + parseInt(color).toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
```

As the above parse int functions truncates leading zeroes, thus produces incorrect color codes of 5 or 4 letters may be... i.e. for rgb(216, 160, 10) it produces #d8a0a while it should be #d8a00a.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This one looks a bit nicer:

```
var rgb = $('#selector').css('backgroundColor').match(/\d+/g);
var r   = parseInt(rgb[0], 10);
var g   = parseInt(rgb[1], 10);
var b   = parseInt(rgb[2], 10);
var hex = '#'+ r.toString(16) + g.toString(16) + b.toString(16);
```

a more succinct one-liner:

```
var rgb = $('#selector').css('backgroundColor').match(/\d+/g);
var hex = '#'+ Number(rgb[0]).toString(16) + Number(rgb[1]).toString(16) + Number(rgb[2]).toString(16);
```

forcing jQuery to always return hex:

```
$.cssHooks.backgroundColor = {
    get: function(elem) {
        if (elem.currentStyle)
            var bg = elem.currentStyle["backgroundColor"];
        else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
            var bg = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem,
                null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
        }
        if (bg.search("rgb") == -1) {
            return bg;
        } else {
            bg = bg.match(/\d+/g);
            function hex(x) {
                return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
            }
            return "#" + hex(bg[0]) + hex(bg[1]) + hex(bg[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the question was using JQuery, here’s a JQuery plugin based on Daniel Elliott’s code:

```
$.fn.cssAsHex = function(colorProp) {

    var hexDigits = '0123456789abcdef';

    function hex(x) {
        return isNaN(x) ? '00' : hexDigits[(x - x % 16) / 16] + hexDigits[x % 16];
    };

    // Convert RGB color to Hex format
    function rgb2hex(rgb) {
        var rgbRegex = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
        return '#' + hex(rgbRegex[1]) + hex(rgbRegex[2]) + hex(rgbRegex[3]);
    };

    return rgb2hex(this.css(colorProp));
};
```

Use it like:

```
var hexBackgroundColor = $('#myElement').cssAsHex('background-color');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution I found that does not throw scripting errors in IE:
http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/29/convert-rgb-to-hex.aspx

Comment: In older versions of IE, fetching a color value of an object using jquery can sometimes return hex instead of rgb, while most modern browsers return RGB. The linked to function handles both use cases

Answer (score 2):

Steven Pribilinskiy's answer drops leading zeroes, for example #ff0000 becomes #ff00.

A solution is to append a leading 0 and substring off the last 2 digits.

```
var rgb = $('#selector').css('backgroundColor').match(/\d+/g);
var hex = '#'+ String('0' + Number(rgb[0]).toString(16)).slice(-2) + String('0' + Number(rgb[1]).toString(16)).slice(-2) + String('0' + Number(rgb[2]).toString(16)).slice(-2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Improved function "hex"

```
function hex(x){
    return isNaN(x) ? "00" : hexDigits[x >> 4] + hexDigits[x & 0xf];
    // or option without hexDigits array
    return (x >> 4).toString(16)+(x & 0xf).toString(16);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, also does [touppercase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) by the use of an argument and checks for other possible white-spaces and capitalisation in the supplied string.

```
var a = "rgb(10, 128, 255)";
var b = "rgb( 10, 128, 255)";
var c = "rgb(10, 128, 255 )";
var d = "rgb ( 10, 128, 255 )";
var e = "RGB ( 10, 128, 255 )";
var f = "rgb(10,128,255)";
var g = "rgb(10, 128,)";

var rgbToHex = (function () {
    var rx = /^rgb\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)$/i;

    function pad(num) {
        if (num.length === 1) {
            num = "0" + num;
        }

        return num;
    }

    return function (rgb, uppercase) {
        var rxArray = rgb.match(rx),
            hex;

        if (rxArray !== null) {
            hex = pad(parseInt(rxArray[1], 10).toString(16)) + pad(parseInt(rxArray[2], 10).toString(16)) + pad(parseInt(rxArray[3], 10).toString(16));

            if (uppercase === true) {
                hex = hex.toUpperCase();
            }

            return hex;
        }

        return;
    };
}());

console.log(rgbToHex(a));
console.log(rgbToHex(b, true));
console.log(rgbToHex(c));
console.log(rgbToHex(d));
console.log(rgbToHex(e));
console.log(rgbToHex(f));
console.log(rgbToHex(g));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/u6LCD/)

Speed comparison on [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/rgbtohex-comparison)

A further improvement could be to `trim()` the `rgb` string

```
var rxArray = rgb.trim().match(rx),
```

Answer (score 1):

My beautiful non-standard solution

**HTML**

```
<div id="selector" style="background-color:#f5b405"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#selector").attr("style").replace("background-color:", "");
```

**Result**

```
#f5b405
```

Comment: It returns everything in the style. :c

Comment: Also only works, if the background-color is set via style, not if it's set via class

Answer (score 1):

[Convert RGB to Hex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63694374/13020119)

I am using Jasmine protractor and I was getting errors like
`- Expected [ 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)' ] to contain '#fff'.`
Below function worked fine for me.

```
function RGBAToHexA(test:string) {
let sep = test.toString().indexOf(",") > -1 ? "," : " ";
const rgba = test.toString().substring(5).split(")")[0].split(sep);
console.log(rgba)
let r = (+rgba[0]).toString(16),
  g = (+rgba[1]).toString(16),
  b = (+rgba[2]).toString(16),
  a = Math.round(+rgba[3] * 255).toString(16);

    if (r.length == 1)
        r = "0" + r;
    if (g.length == 1)
        g = "0" + g;
    if (b.length == 1)
        b = "0" + b;
    if (a.length == 1)
        a = "0" + a;

return "#" + r + g + b + a;
```

}

```
describe('Check CSS', function() {
 
it('should check css of login page', async function(){
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
        browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.css('.btn-auth, .btn-auth:hover'))).perform(); // mouse hover on button
        csspage.Loc_auth_btn.getCssValue('color').then(function(color){
            console.log(RGBAToHexA(color))
            expect( RGBAToHexA(color)).toContain(cssData.hoverauth.color);

        })
```

Comment: You can replace `if (r.length == 1) ... r = "0" + r;` by `*.padStart(2, "0")`

Answer (score 1):

To all the Functional Programming lovers, here is a somewhat functional approach :)

```
const getHexColor = (rgbValue) =>
  rgbValue.replace("rgb(", "").replace(")", "").split(",")
    .map(colorValue => (colorValue > 15 ? "0" : "") + colorValue.toString(16))
    .reduce((acc, hexValue) => acc + hexValue, "#")
```

then use it like:

```
const testRGB = "rgb(13,23,12)"
getHexColor(testRGB)
```

Answer (score 1):

my compact version

```js
//Function to convert rgb color to hex format
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    if(/^#/.test(rgb))return rgb;// if returns colors as hexadecimal
    let re = /\d+/g;
    let hex = x => (x >> 4).toString(16)+(x & 0xf).toString(16);
    return "#"+hex(re.exec(rgb))+hex(re.exec(rgb))+hex(re.exec(rgb));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

full cases (rgb, rgba, transparent...etc) solution (coffeeScript)

```
 rgb2hex: (rgb, transparentDefault=null)->
    return null unless rgb
    return rgb if rgb.indexOf('#') != -1
    return transparentDefault || 'transparent' if rgb == 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+))?\)$/);
    hex = (x)->
      ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2)

    '#' + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

The [**colord**](https://github.com/omgovich/colord) package might be the best choice which is tiny but powerful.

```js
import { colord } from "colord";

colord("rgb(192, 192, 192)").toHex();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi here's my solution after getting the element's color with Javascript

```
function rgb_hex(rgb_string_js){ //example: "rgb(102,54,255)"
  var new_rgb_list = rgb_string_js.replace("rgb(","").replace(")","").split(",");
  return ("#" + parseInt(new_rgb_list[0]).toString(16) + parseInt(new_rgb_list[1]).toString(16) + parseInt(new_rgb_list[2]).toString(16)); 
}
```