# how to display two li in time intervel using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
color:green;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
 setInterval(findYellow,1000);    
 function findYellow()
{
  $("ul").each(function()
{
   var $this = $(this);
   if($this.css("color") != "green")
{
    $this.css("color", "green");
   $this.text("abcd blue");
   }
else
{
    $this.css("color", "blue");
     $this.text("abcd green");
   }
  });
 }

});
</script>
</head>



    <body>
        <ul>This is a sample set
            <li>1</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>9</li>
        </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add a detailed description of the question, dont really understand what you want..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it *without* JQuery

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li id='one' style='display:none'>One</li>
  <li id='two' style='display:none'>Two</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
function showOne() {
  document.getElementById('one').style.display = '';
}

function showTwo() {
  document.getElementById('two').style.display = '';
}

setTimeout(showOne,1000);
setTimeout(showTwo,2000);
```

You can also get list elements by their index, using the `.childNodes[]` array property of any `<ul>` object.

Comment: want to replace that list with another text  in time intervel

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("li")
```

instead of

```
$("ul").
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the colors of `li` independently then use `$("ul li")` instead of `$("ul")`, this iterate through each `li` elements under the `ul` element.

I think there are more problems with your code `$().css("color")` returns `RGB` value instead of the color `green` so you `if` condition will always fail.

Use the method provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/jquery-get-hex-value-rather-rgb) to convert the rgb value to hex value and then compare the values.

Check a working solution in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cFCMN/).

Need more information about the li in same interval portion of the question.