# jQuery - get element background color in hex

Tags: jquery, css, styles, background-color

i'm trying getting elements background colors

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each('.log-widget',function(){
    console.log($(this).css('backgroundColor'));
    //$(this).css({'box-shadow':'1px 1px 20px'+});
   });
  });
```

it doesn't works it send me back `:TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a`

i would like to grab background-color of each element and return that into hex color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're iterating a string which is not what you're after. You want `.each`:

```
$(".log-widget").each(function() { ... });
```

Alternatively, you can use `$.each`, but with a jQuery set:

```
$.each($(".log-widget"), function() { ... });
```

In any case, you *will* have to create a set from the selector string.

Answer (score 2):

As [@pimvdb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514749/pimvdb) pointed out, your `.each` syntax was wrong. To return hexadecimal colors, though, there isn't a native way. You'll have to do the conversion yourself. Take a look at this answer to a similar question: [little link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6177502/364869).

Comment: +1, good point. I noticed that on Chrome, the solution you linked to only accounts for elements in the DOM. Disconnected elements don't seem to have a color like `red` converted to hex/rgb.