# Getting a Html element background Color With JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Well, I have a function to get the background color of a clicked html element. however, as I set the background color via css, with a class, the object`s background color in x.style.background just returns "";

My code: 
Html:

```
<li onclick="setCor(this)" id="vermelho" class="vermelho">Vermelho</li>
```

The JS function:

```
function setCor(x){
    cor = x.style.backgroundColor;
}
```

And the .vermelho class:

```css
.vermelho{
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

How can I get the css value via JS? I can't use jQuery for it, need to be just JS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a style attribute from a css class by javascript/jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965515/how-to-get-a-style-attribute-from-a-css-class-by-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

element.style only returns the inline style attributes (see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style#Notes)

You might be better off using [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle). That however returns an RGB color which you might want to convert to hex if you desire.

```
function setCor(x) {
  cor = window.getComputedStyle(x, null)['background-color'];
}
```

Comment: getComputedStyle() is not implemented by <=IE8, to work in IE add currentStyle to the above code.

Comment: Thanks ComFreek for your help. And Spencer Leonard too.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a note at the @Ixe answer's.

You may want to use this function to convert the value from RGB to HEX:

**Javascript**

```
function hex(x) { return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2); }
```

**Example**

```
function toHex(value) { return "#" + hex(value[0]) + hex(value[1]) + hex(value[2]) }
```

Code taken from this guy [Can I force jQuery.css("backgroundColor") returns on hexadecimal format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177454/can-i-force-jquery-cssbackgroundcolor-returns-on-hexadecimal-format)