# IE11 rendering wrong RGB code?

Tags: jquery, css, background-color, internet-explorer-11

I have defined a constant with hexadecimal color code like this:-

```
var textboxModifySuccessColor = '#E7FBBD';
```

In my JS code, I am using this variable to set the background-color using jQuery css method like this:-

```
$(this).find('option:selected').css('background-color', textboxModifySuccessColor);
```

But, When I am trying to retrieve the same using `css` method I am getting it in `rgb` format like this:-

```
rgb(10, 36, 106)
```

I have used the function mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999209/how-to-get-the-background-color-code-of-an-element) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value) one too but it is returning `#0A246A` instead of `#E7FBBD`. I have also tried the [CSS Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177454/can-i-force-jquery-cssbackgroundcolor-returns-on-hexadecimal-format) solution but it is returning me `highlight`. What I should do to get exactly the same color in hexadecimal format i.e. `#E7FBBD`?

P.S.- It was working fine in IE 7, but this problem started with IE 11.

**Update:**-

I have reviewed my code again and found that the conversion by the method given is perfect, the problem is while rendering the code itself, I have printed the hexadecimal color(as I have defined) and it's rgb equivalent (as rendered by browser) onto the console like this:-

```
console.log("Before-" + textboxModifySuccessColor);
$(this).find('option:selected').css('background-color', textboxModifySuccessColor);
console.log("AfterSet-" + $(this).find('option:selected').css('background-color'));
```

This is giving me below ouput:-

```
Before-#E7FBBD
AftreSet-rgb(10, 36, 106)
```

But, When I tried converting the `E7FBBD` hexadecimal code using [this](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rgbtohex.htm), the actual rgb should be : `rgb(231,251,189)`. Is the browser rendering it wrong?

Here is my JS code:-

```
$(document).delegate('.myDDlClass', 'change', function () {
        var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
        var someText= $.trim(currentRow.find('td select.clsTest').val());
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td select.clsTest').css("background-color", textBoxOriginalBackgroundColor);
        $(this).find('option').css('background-color', textBoxOriginalBackgroundColor);
        if (someText!= SelectDefaultValue) {
            $(this).find('option:selected').css('background-color', textboxModifySuccessColor); //Problem here
        }
    });
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt - Please read the question properly, I have already mentioned I have tried that but it's not working for me.

Comment: Can you post the hook code you are using?

Comment: @Muggles - Exactly same as it is in the mentioned thread.

Comment: @RahulSingh Have a look at http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Retrieve-Hex-Code-of-RGB-format-color-to-avoid-cross-browser-back-color-issue-1004.php

Comment: in your console.log before statement, put `console.log("Before-" + $(this).find('option:selected').css('background-color')`  instead, see if the color even changes

Comment: @sircapsalot - Okay I have placed another console b4 and found, that it is still printing `rgb(10, 36, 106)`, then I went ahead and analyzed the code more and found that somewhere we are setting al the options like this: `$(this).find('option').css('background-color', textBoxOriginalBackgroundColor);` where textBoxOriginalBackgroundColor is `transparent`, thnx I didn't noticed it was not updating the color as well. But why it is not updating?

Comment: it's most likely the context of `this`.  can you show the surrounding js?

Comment: @sircapsalot - Please check my update with my JS.