# how can I get the Hexadecimal value from RGB with javascript?

Tags: jquery, rgb

What is the best method in javascript to get hexadecimal value from:

```
$(this).css("background-color")
```

Comment: which browser? Different browsers return different response formats

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177454/can-i-force-jquery-cssbackgroundcolor-returns-on-hexadecimal-format