# JQuery css() selector to set background-color from class

Tags: jquery, css, background-color

Apologies... I know there are hundreds of questions like this... but I haven't found one which answers what I'm trying to do.

CSS

```
.inputtable {
  background-color: #ffff66; // yellow
}
.inputtable[ disabled ] {
  background-color: #ddd; // greyed-out
}
```

JQuery

```
ajaxGetAddresses.done(function( data, textStatus ) {
    console.log( 'data length: ' + data.length );

    // clear the select
    var s2 = $( '#add_select' );
    s2.empty();
    if( data.length > 1 ){
        // ... select will be "live" 
        s2.prop( 'disabled', false );
        //s2.css( 'background-color', '#ffff66' );
        s2.css( 'background-color', '.inputtable background-color' );
    } else {
        s2.prop( 'disabled', true );
        // s2.css( 'background-color', '#ddd' );
        s2.css( 'background-color', '.inputtable[disabled] background-color' );
    }
```

I hope this makes sense: if there are 0 or 1 elements (arrays) in `data` then I want the `SELECT` to be disabled.  And have a grey background.  Otherwise I want it to have a yellow background, showing that it can be used.

The "hard-coded" versions of the css commands to set `background-color` work fine... I'm just unable to work out how I "retrieve" the `background-color` values from this class (normal and disabled).

**Extra details**

HTML looks like this:

```
  <div id="div1" >
    <div id="select_div" ><u>S</u>elect: 
    <select id="secondname_dropdown" size="1" class="inputtable"  ></select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

...

```
  <div id="address_number">
    Address <select id='add_select' class='inputtable' ></select> 
    of <span id='number_of_addresses' ></span>
  </div>
```

Comment: You should use `addClass()`, `removeClass()`,  `attr()` and `removeAttr()` methods.

Comment: Why use JavaScript and not make other CSS rules that apply to these elements?

Comment: @epascarello ... yes, I thought someone might ask that! I have found that certain page elements don't seem to "automatically refresh".  I.e. change to disabled and I'm seemingly not automatically getting the disabled colour.  I've looked up "refreshing" page elements but no joy there.  Obviously I'm quite a newb.

Comment: because setting false does not remove the attribute

Comment: do you have multiple input?  show us the html you have for the select and `#add_select` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this may help you.

```
ajaxGetAddresses.done(function( data, textStatus ) {
    console.log( 'data length: ' + data.length );
    // clear the select
    var s2 = $( '#add_select' );
    s2.empty();
    if( data.length > 1 ){
        // ... select will be "live" 
        s2.prop( 'disabled', false );
        //s2.css( 'background-color', '#ffff66' );
        s2.addClass( 'inputtable' );
    } else {
        s2.prop( 'disabled', true );
        // s2.css( 'background-color', '#ddd' );
        s2.addClass( 'inputtable').attr("disabled", 'disabled');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks... in fact the SELECT is already class "inputtable".  See comment under Waldemarice.

Comment: U can use this alternative then `ajaxGetAddresses.done(function( data, textStatus ) {
    console.log( 'data length: ' + data.length );
    // clear the select
    var s2 = $( '#add_select' );
    s2.empty();
    if( data.length > 1 ){
        // ... select will be "live" 
        s2.prop( 'disabled', false );
        //s2.css( 'background-color', '#ffff66' );
        s2.toggleClass( 'inputtable' );
    } else {
        s2.prop( 'disabled', true );
        // s2.css( 'background-color', '#ddd' );
        s2.toggleClass( 'inputtable').attr("disabled", 'disabled');
    }`

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly, you explicitely want the hex value for the background color of a given class. To do so, you can access properties of your CSS by using the .css() function, like the following:

```
$('.inputtable[disabled] background-color').css('background-color');
```

This'll return the color to you in an RGB format. This [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6177502/7448372) describes how to convert the RBG into a hex value.

Comment: That selector makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

```
.inputtable {
  background-color: #ffff66; // yellow
}

.inputtable-disabled {
  background-color: #ddd; // greyed-out
}

ajaxGetAddresses.done(function( data, textStatus ) {
  console.log('data length: ' + data.length)

  // clear the select
  var s2 = $('#add_select')
  s2.empty()
  if (data.length > 1) {
    // ... select will be "live" 
    s2.prop('disabled', false)
    //s2.css( 'background-color', '#ffff66' );
    s2.removeClass('inputtable-disabled').addClass('inputtable')
} else {
    s2.prop( 'disabled', true );
    // s2.css( 'background-color', '#ddd' );
    s2.removeClass('inputtable').addClass('inputtable-disabled')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to control the disabled logic, then CSS will apply the color itself.

Check this example:

```js
/* if (data.length > 1) {
  // ... select will be "live" 
  s2.prop('disabled', false);
} else {
  s2.prop('disabled', true);
} */


$('#tog').on('click', function() {
  if ($('.inputtable').prop('disabled') == true) {
    $('.inputtable').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('.inputtable').prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```css
.inputtable {
  background-color: #ffff66; // yellow
}

.inputtable[ disabled] {
  background-color: #ddd; // greyed-out
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="add_select" class="inputtable">

</select>
<select id="add_select" class="inputtable">

</select>
<select id="add_select" class="inputtable">

</select>

<button id="tog">Toggle disabled</button>
```

Comment: Thanks... yes, I'm getting quite confused... indeed what I initially set out to do was just to set the disabled property, hoping that the elements on the page would automatically update their appearance immediately.  But somehow that didn't seem to happen!  Will study and continue to experiment...

Comment: @mikerodent wait, show me the HTML you have for the select and the id `add_select`