# JQuery click+this not working

Tags: jquery

I have copied a snippet of code over.  I am very new to web languages and come from a java background.

JQuery seems great but I just can't figure out how to solve this.

http://jsfiddle.net/MMf9Q/2/

thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In future, please don't *just* include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should standalone from any other resource; consider what'd happen if jsFiddle went down in the future.

Comment: Toggling classes is easier than editing styles directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle to work as I think you are expecting it.

I removed the if/else statement and simple used jQuery toggle ability(http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).  Made a class that I want the object to transform to.  I find this keeps the code much cleaner and organized.

Fixed code:
http://jsfiddle.net/MMf9Q/6/

jQuery:

```
    $('#clickme').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('red');
    })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In future, please don't *just* include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should standalone from any other resource; consider what'd happen if jsFiddle went down in the future.

Comment: Agreed! Also OP, when inside your click function  THIS is a reference to your clicked element.  If you want to perform jquery operations on the element, you need to wrap it in $()

Comment: and jsfiddle links are not blank, leaving the page is annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Answers21241 and iambriansreed have lovely answers which gives what you tried to accomplish.

But for your code, I would like to give couple of advices for start.

First of all, here is your original javascript code:

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){

    var color = this.css('background');

    if(color == '#cc0000'){
        this.css('background', '#00CC00');
    }else{
        this.css('background', '#CC0000');
    }
})​
```

1) You have to wrap your code in `$(function(){});` in order for jquery to execute it after page load. Otherwise, your javascript code will be executed before DOM is fully loaded, and it will simply not work for most cases:

```
$(function(){
    $('#clickme').click(function(){
        var color = this.css('background-color');
                    alert(color);
        if(color == '#CC0000'){
            this.css('background-color', '#00CC00');
        }else{
            this.css('background-color', '#CC0000');
        }
    });
});​
```

2) `this.css()` will not work. `.css()` is a function of a jquery object, and this is not a jquery object in that case. You must wrap it with `$()` to construct a jquery object from any dom element:

```
$(function(){
    $('#clickme').click(function(){
        var color = $(this).css('background-color');
        if(color == '#CC0000'){
            $(this).css('background-color', '#00CC00');
        }else{
            $(this).css('background-color', '#CC0000');
        }
    });
});​
```

3) color value may be something different than what you gave. Browsers convert hex color values to RGB values mostly, and what you get will differ. Try `alert(color);` at a point to get value, and change your code accordingly.

```
$(function(){
    $('#clickme').click(function(){
        var color = $(this).css('background-color');
                    alert(color);
        if(color == '#CC0000' || color == 'rgb(204, 0, 0)'){
            $(this).css('background-color', '#00CC00');
        }else{
            $(this).css('background-color', '#CC0000');
        }
    });
});​
```

Here is final [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMf9Q/21/):

This will help you to understand what was wrong. Besides, the way is not the best practice. Use toggleClass and style your elements within css. Answers21241 and iambriansreed have given good ways of doing that.

Comment: I believe you have mixed your if statement incorrectly. You are asking if the color is red or green then turn it into green; otherwise nice answer

Comment: Thanks for warning. You are right, it must had been 204, 0, 0. I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Use $(this) to access the this element as a JQuery object

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){

    var color = $(this).css('background-color');

    if(color == '#cc0000'){
        $(this).css('background', '#00CC00');
    }else{
        $(this).css('background', '#CC0000');
    }
})
```

Comment: note that JQuery returns the color as "rgb(r, g, b)" rather than hex - you will have to convert it - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/get-hex-value-rather-than-rgb-value-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

**Fiddled**

http://jsfiddle.net/nTXPC/

**CSS**

```
.red {
 background:#CC0000;
}
.green {
 background:#00CC00;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="clickme" class="red"> Click me </div>​
```

**JS**

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){

   $(this).toggleClass('red green');

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon, your code had a couple of problems with it. The first is that you need to wrap `this` in `$()`. That represents the `#clickme` element.

Secondly, your request for background is a lot more detailed than what you were expecting. You could `alert` or console.log what is being returned to find out why your if statements are not behaving like you were expecting. [As seen here.](http://jsfiddle.net/MMf9Q/8/)

**Update**: Here is the [updated approach](http://jsfiddle.net/MMf9Q/17/):

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
    var color = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
    if(color == "rgb(0, 204, 0)") {
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#CC0000');
    }else{
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#00CC00');
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it should be $(this) instead of this.  I would also recommend saving $(this) to another variable for performance purposes.  It's probably not necessary to do here, but it's a good habit to get in to, especially if you're looping through something.  Something like this:

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){

    var clickedElement = $(this);
    var color = clickedElement.css('background');

    if(color == '#cc0000'){
        clickedElement.css('background', '#00CC00');
    }else{
        clickedElement.css('background', '#CC0000');
    }
})​
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){

    var color = $(this).css('background-color');

    if(color == '#cc0000'){
        $(this).css('background-color', '#00CC00');
    }else{
        $(this).css('background-color', '#CC0000');
    }
})​;
```

Comment: the 'background' that is returned is far more detailed in Chrome than just its hex values.

Comment: Thanks i have modified did it in hurry

Answer (score 0):

Use $(this) instead of this. It represent the selector.