# jquery if background color ==

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check for the background of an element, here is my code. But it doesn't work:

I tried two ways, here is the first:

```
function changeColor(field) {
     if(field.css('background-color','#ffb100')) {
          field.css('background-color','white');
     }
     else {
          field.css('background-color','ffb100');
     }
}
```

here is the second:

```
function changeColor(field) {
     if(field.css('background-color') === '#ffb100') {
          field.css('background-color','white');
     }
     else {
          field.css('background-color','ffb100');
     }
}
```

But neither worked! Any suggestions?

EDIT: This is my latest code, but it still is not working:

```
function changeColor(field) {
                if(field.css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)') {
                    field.css('background-color','ffb100');
                }
                else {
                    field.css('background-color','white');
                }
            }
```

Comment: how styles are added inline or in the external stylesheet-file? It's important

Comment: external stylesheet, but it is undefined at the beginning of the page. it turns to the reddish color once a form is submitted and fields are blank.

Comment: What is `field`? The first obviously cannot work, since `.css('background-color','#ffb100')` **sets** the `background-color` to `#ffb100` and returns the jQuery object.

Comment: try to print the value of the background-color to see in which format you get it (#FFB100 , or #ffb100 or ffb100...)

Comment: You should consider solving the problem by [toggling a class](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) instead of what you're currently doing. e.g. `function changeColor (field) { field.toggleClass('foo'); }`. Have your stylesheet define the colors that `.foo` (and not `.foo`) should use.

Comment: Here's a [fiddle with a toggling example](http://jsfiddle.net/PnhQJ/) - see if it fits what you're trying to do. It uses a `click` handler, but you could use the same concept anywhere.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[From jQuery `.css()` documentation:](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

> Note that the computed style of an element may not be the same as the value specified for that element in a style sheet. For example, computed styles of dimensions are almost always pixels, but they can be specified as `em`, `ex`, `px` or `%` in a style sheet. Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., `#FFF`, `#ffffff`, and `rgb(255,255,255)`.

Most browsers return a `rgb` value, so you can code:

```
if (field.css('background-color') === 'rgb(255, 177, 0)') {
   // ...
}
```

The above snippet, based on the specified reason, may fail in some browsers. You can consider using a color conversion library or create a temporary element and set and get it's `background-color`/`color` property.

A simple jQuery plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.isBgColor = function(color) {
        var thisBgColor = this.eq(0).css('backgroundColor');
        var computedColor = $('<div/>').css({ 
            backgroundColor: color
        }).css('backgroundColor');
        return thisBgColor === computedColor;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
if ( field.isBgColor('#ffb100') ) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: is there no way to have it equal to my hex value? or is there a jquery convert keyword?

Comment: @phileaton You could try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/get-hex-value-rather-than-rgb-value-using-jquery).

Comment: @phileaton unfortunately no, but you can write a function that converts the hex value to a rgb value.

Comment: Note that the spaces in 'rgb(255, 177, 0)' matter, it took me half an hour to figure that out.

Answer (score 5):

As @undefined already said, `css()` will return an `rgb` value for the background-color, which solves your problem, so you should upvote his answer. However, I *strongly* advise you against having fixed colors in your JavaScript.

An alternative is to define two CSS classes, which are the appropriate place to put styles:

```
.orange {
  background-color: #ffb100;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

And then simply toggle the field's class, which is much cleaner than to compare hex or rgb values in your JavaScript, and easier to switch when you want a different color:

```
function changeColor(field) {
  field.toggleClass("white orange");
}
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4pYkM/)**.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `field` is referring to, but my guess stands that it is the **id** of the element?

If so, try wrapping `field` like so `$('#' + field).css`.

**NOTE: Here's a VERY NICE function for converting HEX to RGB**

```
function hexToRgb(string)
{
    if(!string || typeof string !== 'string') return false;

    if(
        string.substring(0,1) == '#' && 
        (string.length == 4 || string.length == 7) && 
        /^[0-9a-fA-F]+$/.test(string.substring(1, string.length))
    ){
    string = string.substring(1, string.length);

    if(string.length == 3) 
        string = string[0] + string[0] + string[1] + string[1] + string[2] + string[2];

    return 'rgb(' + 
        parseInt(string[0] + string[1], 16).toString() + ',' + 
        parseInt(string[2] + string[3], 16).toString() + ',' + 
        parseInt(string[4] + string[5], 16).toString() + 
    ')';
}
else return false;
}
```

Comment: I'd imagine `field` is a jQuery object.

Comment: @xbonez what if field is a DOM node?

Comment: The way he is is using the function argument `field` makes it obvious that field is already a JQuery object. Of course, if it is not, then he'd have to convert it to one first.

Comment: field can be any of 5 vars that reference input elements like this: $('#name'),etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Important**: make sure you type `rgb(128, 128, 128)` with one blank space after the commas. If you type `rgb(128,128, 128)` it won't work. *It's space sensitive*.

Try it: `alert(element.css('background-color') === 'rgb(128, 128, 128)')`

Answering the main question:

```
var style = 'background-color';
var gray = 'rgb(128, 128, 128)';

if(element.css(style) === gray){
  element.css(style,'blue');
}else{
  element.css(style,gray);
}
```