# Check background color in if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an `if` statement with 2 conditions. For some reason it changes the background color to red and never to black.

```
$(".circles").click(function() {
    counter++;
    if (counter % 2 === 0 && $(this).css("background-color")=="#FFFFFF") {
        $(this).css("background-color", "black");
    } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    }
})
```

The `.circles` is set to `#FFFFFF` originally. 
What is wrong?

Comment: `$(this).css("background-color")` will probably be `rgb(255,255,255)`. Never trust colors.

Comment: Further to Oriol's comment instead of testing the colour value (which is difficult, at best, to do reliably), assign the given background-colors to CSS classes and use `toggleClass()` to switch classes from one to the other.

Comment: What is your initial value for variable `counter`? What is the order you want to get: white, black, red, red, red OR white, black, red, black, red OR something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser will probably give you back the `rgb` color if you use `css("background-color")` method, but that is not for sure. If you want to be sure, than create an element with white background and get its property:

```js
var whiteColor = $('<div/>').css({
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
}).css('backgroundColor');
var counter = 0;
$(".circles").click(function() {
    counter++;
    if (counter % 2 === 0 && $(this).css("background-color") == whiteColor) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "black");
    } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    }
})
```

```css
.circles {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circles" style="background-color: #fff;">
    Click me
</div>
```

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124451/jquery-if-background-color#answer-12124493).

Also on [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywx5pjgg/1/).

Comment: Why would you create a stub element to retrieve its color when needed rather than using classes?

Comment: I would not do it that way, I am just following the question so my answer has sense. Theoretically, programmer may not be allowed to change the styles, or those would need approval from higher instance.

Comment: Thanks, this was the easier way for me to do it since it didn't mean for me to redo my code and I understood each step.

Comment: I wasn't saying it doesn't had sense.. Just not getting the point of the workaround.. I was just: "Why?!" Now I got your point :) I'd rather crash everyone for an approval rather than using workarounds, though  :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to log the actual result of the call:

```
$(this).css("background-color")
```

The result (on Chrome) was: `rgb(255,255,255)` hence it is different from the string `"#FFFFFF"`.

Also the problem with the `counter` is that when it's an odd number you set the background-color to red, when it's an even number the background-color is red [returning `rgb(255,0,0)`] and thus it's different from `"#FFFFFF"`.

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5nuuhb1z/3/).

I'd suggest you using a different kind of match.. for instance you could toggle classes on click and use the added classes selector to alter the `background-color`

Using classes instead of `$(this).css(..) == "a color string"` inside the `IF` condition means that you can create a `.white` class which your item has at the start. When clicked, if it has `.white` class than you change its color using another class `.red` (class names are examples, just name them as you wish)

The classes are set to only change the `background-color` in your CSS file, hence they'll be something like:

```
.white{
    background-color: #FFFFFF
}

.red{
    background-color: #FF0000
}
```

Comment: the problem isn't the counter. The counter is working the way it should. I don't want to be able to alter the background-color. I want it to only switch once. That's the issue.

Comment: the problem is how you're handling the color matching inside the `IF` condition and the color switch via jQuery, you should definitely use classes instead of `$(this).css(..) == "a color string"`. For instance you can create a `.white` class which your item as at the start. When clicked, if it has `.white` class than you change its color using another class `.red` (class names are examples, just name them as you wish)

Comment: ah, now I get what you mean. Yeah that sounds like a good way to do it. Gonna try that. Thanks

Comment: you're welcome :)
If the solution worked please accept the answer for future readers