# Checking CSS color with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to check the border-right-color value with jQuery sorta like so:

```
if ($(this).css("border-right-color") == "#000") {
    // Do some magic
}
```

But that doesn't work. `console.log`ing() the value of $(this).css("border-right-color") says `rgb(0,0,0)`.

So, how do I write this conditional check?

Comment: Compare with `rgb(0,0,0,0)` instead of `#000`?

Comment: What colour were you expecting?

Comment: rgb() ain't no kind of object.

Comment: Or you can convert rgb to hex explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value

Comment: More technically: ReferenceError: rgb is not defined

Comment: @Wells, For what matters, `rgb(0,0,0)` is just a string.

Comment: … so you have to quote the string you are comparing it to: `=== "rgb(etc)"`

Comment: Oh good grief: `$(this).css("border-right-color") == "rgb(0, 0, 0)"` works.. At least in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below function found [here](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2009/06/convert-jquery-rgb-output-to-hex-color.html)

```
if (rgb2hex($(this).css("border-right-color")) == "#000") {
    // Do some magic
}


function rgb2hex(rgb){
 rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
 return "#" +
  ("0" + parseInt(rgb[1],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
  ("0" + parseInt(rgb[2],10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
  ("0" + parseInt(rgb[3],10).toString(16)).slice(-2);
}
```

[***Take a look here for a working example***](http://jsfiddle.net/M2j4K/3/)