# how to display hexcolor onclick corresponding colobox Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, colors, background-color

i have a variable like this,

```
var colours = [
    { name: 'Yellow', hex: '#FFFF00' },
    { name: 'LawnGreen', hex: '#7CFC00' },
    { name: 'Aqua', hex: '#00FFFF' },
    { name: 'Fuchsia', hex: '#FF00FF' },
    { name: 'Blue', hex: '#0000FF' },
    { name: 'Red', hex: '#FF0000' }      
];
```

i have a function like this ,

```
$(function()
{
    $('li').live('click', function()
    {
         $('.activeColour').css('background-color', $(this).css('background-color'));       
    });

    var $palette = $('ul');
    for (var i = 0; i < colours.length; i++)
    {
        $palette.append($('<li />').css('background-color', colours[i].hex));
    }
});
```

but while click on particular color, i do not need the rgb color, i need hex color in a variable or alert what will do,This is for document.execcommand please help.

Comment: i need some generic method to do this

Comment: Post yout htm also, or create jsfiddle for this

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GeekyEggo/ajumP/1/ this is the jsfiddle link for this i am not sure who created this but now i need this with better solution, here while onclick on the color it will display the background color, i need the exact hex-code help me

Comment: Its working, what you need more?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value

Comment: if i alert this i will get the rgb color,i just need the exact hex code,i am new in JavaScript please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    red = parseInt(your_red_value).toString(16);
    green = parseInt(your_green_value).toString(16);
    blue = parseInt(your_blue_value).toString(16);
    if(red == 0)
        red = '00';
    if(green == 0)
        green = '00';
    if(blue == 0)
        blue = '00';
    var Hex_value = ('#' + red + green + blue).toUpperCase();
```

[RGB TO HEX CONVERTER](http://jsfiddle.net/Ev49g/)

EDIT: This is what you want

```
var color = $(this).css('background-color').substring($(this).css('background-color').indexOf('(')+1,$(this).css('background-color').indexOf(')')).split(',');
var hex_color ='#'+ parseInt(color[0]).toString(16) + parseInt(color[1]).toString(16) + parseInt(color[2]).toString(16) ;
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajumP/41/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below functions it will convert RGB to hex color

```
 function colorToHex(color) {
        if (color.substr(0, 1) === '#') {
            return color;
        }
        var digits = /(.*?)rgb\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\)/.exec(color);

        var red = parseInt(digits[2]);
        var green = parseInt(digits[3]);
        var blue = parseInt(digits[4]);

        var rgb = blue | (green << 8) | (red << 16);
        return digits[1] + '#' + rgb.toString(16);
    };




   function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
                var rgb = b | (g << 8) | (r << 16);
               return (0x1000000 | rgb).toString(16).substring(1);
            }
```

Thanks,

Siva