# convert rgb color to hex using js or jquery when jquery .css gives rgb

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with jQuery, when I am getting color using jQuery css like this

```
$('#myElement').css('background-color')
```

it gives me RGB color and in my HTML, I use hex colors.

```
<div id="myElement" style="background-color: #ff0000;">some text here</div>
```

I need to convert RGB color to hex using JS or jQuery... for example `rgb(255,0,0)` to `#ff0000`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value

Comment: You can use te toString function of Number also. `(new Number(255)).toString(16)`