# HTML5 input type color doesn't show value when created via js

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a table via javascript and one column will contain an html color picker. The problem that I have is that in Chrome the default value is set but the color that is displayed on the color picker is black.

This is the javascript that I am using

```
c = r.insertCell(1);
c.setAttribute('class','second');
inp=document.createElement("input"); 
inp.setAttribute('type','color');
inp.setAttribute('id','colo_'+i);
inp.setAttribute('value','#ffffff');
inp.setAttribute('class','datafield');
inp.addEventListener('change', saveFields);
c.appendChild(inp);
```

This is the html that is generated from if

<td class="second">
    <input type="color" id="colo_0" value="#8080ff" class="datafield">
</td>

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting. I was able to replicate your results ([example](http://jsbin.com/odOyoMe/1/edit)).

Rather than using `setAttribute`, set the `value` directly:

```
inp.value = '#ffffff';
```

Apparently that makes Chrome happy. ([Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ivAhORu/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ivAhORu/1/edit))

---

Side note: All of the things you're setting via `setAttribute` have reflected properties you can use instead:

```
inp = document.createElement("input"); 
inp.type = 'color';
inp.id = 'colo_'+i;
inp.value = '#ffffff';
inp.className = 'datafield';
```

Note that the last one is `className` rather than `class`.

[Updated Example](http://jsbin.com/ivAhORu/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ivAhORu/2/edit)

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful for someone someday, so I'll just put it here:
The value of input color seems to work only with hex value (rather than RGB) - so if your color is in RGB - switch it to hex first. [RGB to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value)