# Get the border color of a dynamic image then print it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been wondering if such an action is possible to accomplish and which language would be required.

Let's assume I have a image with a `border:1px solid #333`

```
+------------+
|            |
|   image    | 
|   border   |
|   is       |
|   #333;    |
|            |
+------------+
```

Once the page is refreshed it automatically updates to another image where it is a different color. Now, is it possible to somehow identify the 1px of the image border(#333) and then print that color?

Comment: Check in Developer Console in browser.

Answer (score 2):

**You don't need to use jQuery to do this.**

Pure JS approach using [**`getComputedStyle()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle) and `getPropertyValue()`.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/KJ29Q/)

```
el_style = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('some_element'));
el_border_color = el_style.getPropertyValue('border-color');

alert(el_border_color); //"rgb(255,0,0)"
```

Comment: Finally the voice of reason!

Comment: Thanks for the only JS solution, even though, ironically, that's what was asked for.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you could get the border color with:

```
var color = $('#img').css("border-color");
```

### Return result in rgb (e.g. rgb(44,44,44))

```
$("#result").html(color);
```

### Return result in hex (e.g. #ff0000)

```
function to_hex(color) {

    var chars = /(.*?)rgb\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\)/.exec(color);

    var red = parseInt(chars[2]);
    var green = parseInt(chars[3]);
    var blue = parseInt(chars[4]);

    var rgb = blue | (green << 8) | (red << 16);
    return chars[1] + '#' + rgb.toString(16);
};


$("#result").html(to_hex(color));
```

Comment: OP didn't ask for jQuery!!

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery. Assuming the following HTML for the image:

```
<img id="myImage" src="foo.jpg" alt="foo" />
```

you can get the color of border with:

```
$('#myImage').css('border-color')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to get the color of the border, and then write that to an HTML element.

```
var imgBorderColor = $('img').css('border-color');
$('#output').html(imgBorderColor);
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5Y7M/4/)

This will output the color as an RGB.  If you need hex, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value).

Comment: OP didn't ask for jQuery!!