# Google Chrome giving rgb() after I set hexadecimal

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, colors

I assign an element's background color using a hex code.

```
e.style.backgroundColor = '#7bf47e'
```

When I come back later to ASK for that color, so I can see if it's changed or not, Chrome gives me an `RGB() triplet: rgb(123,123,123)`.

Since `'#7bf47e'` does not equal `'rgb(123,123,123)'`, the color has always changed as far as Chrome is concerned.

IE10 handles this fine, giving me `'#7bf47e'` when I ask for the background color.

---

EDIT: Sorry, here's a clarification. The actual rgb values below are purely for example.  I didn't note what the actual rgb() values were.  I'm just saying that I give it a hex, and it gives me back an rbg().  I'd like to get it back in the same format I set it.

Comment: Are you saying Chrome gives you a completely random RGB triplet every time you ask for it?

Comment: You mention `rgb(123,123,123)` and `rgb(1,2,3)`, which is it?

Comment: Are you sure you're clicking on the correct element? Also, in Chrome you can always shift-click on the color swatch next to a color in dev tools to switch between `rgb`, hex, and `hsl`.

Comment: Sorry, guys. My bad. The actual rgb values are purely for example. 

I didn't note what the actual rgb() values were. 

I'm just saying that I give it a hex, and it gives me back an rbg(). I'd like to get it back in the same format I set it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be consistent across browsers, but workarounds exist for taking the RGB triplet and converting to hex manually. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value

Answer (score 0):

`#7BF47E` is equal to `rgb(123, 244, 126)`

whereas `rgb(123, 123, 123)` is `#7B7B7B`

it seems like chrome changed background color you set.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the browser represents all colors internally as RBG() triplets.

So, even if you set a hexadecimal color, or even a color name, internally to Chrome it will be converted to `rgb(nnn,nnn,nnn)`.  This behaviour is by design, and you simply have to anticipate and work with that.