# Getting all colors from a div with jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

Is it possible to get all colorvalues that exist in a div with a certain class, and its child elements?

for example, i have:

```
<div class="row client">
<a href="somepage.php" style="color:#515151;">Link1</a>
<span style="color:#f3f3f3;">Span</span>
<h3 style="color:#ff00ff;">Subtitle</h3>
</div>
```

I want an array to get all colors:

```
background of the parent div
color of the <a> element
color of the <span> element
color of the <h3> element
```

Also, i'm using [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) to display charts in the same div. Is it possible to get the colors used there aswell?

I don't think i can put this any clearer for you guys,

Many thanks!

Job

Comment: Are all these color inline styles only? not in stylesheet?..

Comment: In highcharts the color are hardcoded values so i dont think u need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just loop through all the elements in the div

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1pcbp47/)

```
var elements =  $(".client").children()

$(elements).each(function(index) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $(this).css("color"));
});
```

Comment: Some advice on this: You're missing a semi-colon on the first line. Be consistent, either use one or don't. The `index` variable doesn't represent an index, it's an element, you should name it appropriately. `$(elements)` is not required, `elements` is already a jQuery object.

Comment: couple of things. it is not considering parent tag, no tagname info is retrieved,

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
var colorarray=[];
$('.client').children().addBack().each(function(){
  if(!$(this).is('.client'))
     colorarray.push("color of the <" +$(this).prop("tagName")+"> is "+ $(this).css('color'))
  else
     colorarray.push("background of <" +$(this).prop("tagName")+"> is "+ $(this).css('backgroundColor'))
})
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/354gnk84/)**

If you want the color in hex, you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1740716/1719752

Comment: As per question, you should add the background-color. I'm also not sure, if any other color should be included, like border-color etc.

Comment: This works, but the code from Jacques seems more simple. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: It's more simple because it doesn't address the problem like this answer *actually* does

Comment: @RGraham: indeed yes. with tag name info and background color for first tag

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a rather inefficient but, I think, easy to understand approach without libraries:

```js
let allNodes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'));

let setOfColors = allNodes.reduce((colors,el) => {
  return colors.add(getComputedStyle(el).backgroundColor)
}, new Set)


let arrayOfColors = Array.from(setOfColors);
```