# Find a div by color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to find a div which has the following color: `#ff8533`.

Is it possible to find a div by color using Jquery?

If found, is it possible to then retrieve any text contained within it?

Comment: Not sure why this question got that many downvotes please clarify.

Comment: This is not a proper duplicate, color of an element doesn't mean it has a data attribute. If it's defined in CSS (which is true in most cases) the "duplicate" isn't helpful at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you get the color value of an element by it's computed style:

```
$(selector).css('color');
```

But, the above would return the `RGB` value even though the color is set as `hex` value. Hence, you'd need a function to convert `RGB` to `hex`.

So, the bottom line is, filter the `div` elements to return the one that matches the color specified, store it in a variable, then do whatever with that variable, such as, get the containing text etc. Take a look at the example below.

**Only tested on major browsers and IE9+**

```js
var matchedDiv = $("div").filter(function() {
    return rgb2hex($(this).css("color")) === "#ff8533"
});

alert (matchedDiv.css('border', '1px solid black').text());

//Credit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3971432/572827
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(\d+))?\)$/);
    function hex(x) {
        return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="color: red;">Demo2</div>
<div class="demo" style="color: #ff8533;">The one I am after</div>
<div style="color: green;">Demo3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript  : you could make a loop where you check all your div, and check the color parameter value with the following code :

```
var listDivs = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (i = 0; i<listDivs.length; i++){
    div=listDivs[i];
    if(window.getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue('color')=='#ff8533'){
        text = div.textContent; // use innerHTML if you want the HTML
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to find a `div` by it's color and it depends on how the color is set. If it is set by an attribute like so:

```
<div bgcolor="red">Hello World</div>
```

Then you can simply access the attribute of that element in jQuery like so:

```
$('div[bgcolor="red"]');
```

When it's defined via css or as a `style` like:

```
<div style="background-color: red">Hello World</div>
```

Then you will need to `filter` the element you are looking through and find the item of the color you want, for example `red` would be `rgb(255, 0, 0)`. That would look like:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'; // red
});
```

To find an element by text you simply need to use the [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

[**Here is an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/01pk3s7s/1/)

Answer (score 0):

#### Using javascript you can find all div tags and check the color attribute

```
/*
 * this method take element you want to find
 * and color to match
 */
function getElementByColor(element,color)
{
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName(element);
    var ret = null;
    for(var i=0; i<elem.length; ++i)
    {
        if(elem[i].style.color == color)
        {
            ret = elem[i].innerHTML;
            /*
             * or`enter code here`
             *  ret[txt] = elem[i].textContent;
             */
        }
    }
    
    return ret;
}
window.onload = function()
{
    if(txt = getElementByColor("div","#ff8533"))
    {
        // do something
    }
};
```