# Javascript to check if <td> is of a particular background colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just getting to grips with javascript and jquery

I am setting `backgroundColor` of a table cell based on its value.

```
 $("td.ms-vb2").filter(function(index){return $(this).text() === "Yes";}).css("backgroundColor", "#81F79F");
 $("td.ms-vb2").filter(function(index){return $(this).text() === "No";}).css("backgroundColor", "#FE642E");
```

Could someone tell me how I would be able write an if-else statement where if the color is `#81F79F` do an alert and if the color is `#FE642E`, do another alert

OR

if the value in the cell is *Yes* do an alert and if the value in the cell is *No*, do another alert

Many thanks

Comment: You want those alerts to run when? They will run on a loop? Isn't this annoying ?

Answer (score 1):

Grab the color from the element, then check it as you wish. Since jQuery seems to return `background-color` as an rgb color, you would either have to convert it to hex, or check against the equivalent rgb.

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value) if you want a function to convert the color value.

```
var color = $('td.ms-vb2').css('background-color');
if (color == 'rgb(129,247,159)')
    alert('#81F79F');
else if (color == 'rgb(254,100,46)')
    alert('#FE642E');
```

Alternatively, you could do a similar bit of code to check the text (this is probably the easier solution in this case)

```
var value = $('td.ms-vb2').text();
alert(value == "Yes" ? "Yes!" : "No...");
```

Comment: Can you show how to get the background color in hex ?

Comment: Ah just realized that it returns in rgb, let me update my answer

Answer (score 1):

your best bet is to probably add a class to the td if it is yes, or a different class if it is no.  and then test basis existence of the class.

for example add the class `affirmative` or `negative`

then in your css have a style for affirmative or negative and declare the background-color there.  that way, all your js needs to do is change the class

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each()` function to do all what you need:

Set cell background-color:

```
$('td.ms-vb2').each(function(){
    var cell = $(this)
    if (cell.text() == "Yes")
        cell.css('background-color', '#81F79F');
    else if (cell.text() == "No")
        cell.css('background-color', '#FE642E');        
});
```

Show alerts:

```
$('td.ms-vb2').each(function(){
    var color = $(this).css('background-color');
    if (color == '#81F79F')
        alert('#81F79F');
    else alert('another color');
});
```