# DOMParser - get element style

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, domparser

I'm trying to get a style property of an element that I parse with DOMParser. The 2 console.logs come up empty though. Any idea why this happens?

```
<div id='foobar'>
  <style>
  .xl496
    {
    color:#336699;
    }
  </style>

  <table>
   <tr>
    <td class='xl496'>Test:</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

```
var data = document.getElementById("foobar");

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(data.innerHTML, "text/html");
var cols = doc.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var col = cols[0];
var tds = col.getElementsByTagName("td");
var td = tds[0];

console.log(getComputedStyle(td).getPropertyValue("color"));
console.log(td.style.color);
```

Comment: Do you have to use the DOMParser?

Comment: Yes. Because later on I'm planning to get the data from the clipboard like this  e.clipboardData.getData('text/html');

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) is a method that is only available to the window. Since your code is inside of a DOM parser, it does not have the right context, and therefore returns empty strings back in that call. So, here is a way to get around it. You can take the element in question, insert it into the window, run the `getComputedStyle` and then put it back into the DOMParser (fragment).

```js
var clipboardData = document.getElementById("foobar").outerHTML;


var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(clipboardData, "text/html");

var col = doc.querySelector("tr");
var td = col.querySelector("td");

// td has to be in the window, not a fragment in order to use window.getComputedStyle
document.body.appendChild(td);

console.log(window.getComputedStyle(td).getPropertyValue("color"));
// the next one expected to be "" since it does not have inline styles
console.log(td.style.color);

// Insert the td back into the dom parser where it was
col.insertBefore(td, col.firstChild);
```

```html
<div id='foobar'>
  <style>
    .xl496 {
      color: #336699;
    }
  </style>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class='xl496'>Test:</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

You can look at a solution to convert RGB to HEX with something from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value)

Comment: Sure. I could do that. But I'm planning to add clipboard integration as the next step. So I would get the data from e.clipboardData.getData('text/html');