# Using jQuery filter on all elements based on background-color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, filter

I'm currently using a generated html code.

I'm trying to select all elements and then filter those who got the same background-color and change it.
My current code, which is not working:

```
$('*').filter(function(){
   return $(this).css('background-color') === '#0689cb';
}).css('background-color', 'green');
```

It returns a lot of elements, but it doesn't change anything.

If I try the .length like this:

```
$('*').filter(function(){
   return $(this).css('background-color') === '#0689cb';
}).length;
```

Will return 0, which means, it is not getting anything.

What am I doing wrong with my filter function?

Oh, and I tried the selector with $('div') to see if it was something wrong with the selector, but it didn't change anything.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: i pretty sure the background-color doesn't return Hex format but rgb ... i saw a question like this before, but not able to find it :)

Comment: Oh, I tried the rgb as well, it didn't work @TemaniAfif

Comment: yes but you need to pay attention to some spaces, as it's returned as string .. you can do a console.log and you will see how

Comment: To provide an example of @TemaniAfif's point: https://jsfiddle.net/x9zcaqjr/ - `background-color: red;` outputs `rgb(255, 0, 0)`, spacing and all.

Comment: simple `console.log($(this).css('background-color'))` would show why it fails

Comment: It returns rgb??? Like .e.g. rgb(255, 255, 255)

Comment: Oh, I got it now. Sorry if it looked like a dumb question (regarding the downvote which I have no idea why tho).
I'm really new into js.
Now that I now my mistake I can fix it. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @Gogol why are you surprised ? yes it returns like this ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif surprised because of the question, not rgb :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an RGB value and you need to write the values with commas and spaces between them.

Below is a function (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)) that will convert valid hex codes to the correct RGB string.

```js
$('*').filter(function(){
  return $(this).css('background-color') === hexToRgb('#0689cb');
}).css('background-color', 'green');

function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    
    // Correct string should be like: "rgb(6, 137, 203)" <-- note the spaces
    return "rgb(" + 
        parseInt(result[1], 16) + ", " + 
        parseInt(result[2], 16) + ", " +
        parseInt(result[3], 16) + ")";
}
```

```css
.colorToFind {
  background-color:#0689cb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="colorToFind">hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
<div class="colorToFind">hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about the spaces tho, I think that was my mistake.
Thanks for the assistance, I'll adapt it accordingly to my scenario.
I'll make it the accepted question for the snippet, even tho all the other answers provided my mistake. Thanks to you all guys! @charlietfl

Comment: have seen some browsers in past return `rgba` also. Chrome did for a while but seemed to hve reverted back to rgb

Answer (score 1):

`background-color` will return `rgb`. You'll need to find the RGB value of your the hex code and use that in your conditional.

```
$('*').filter(function() {
   return $(this).css('background-color') === 'rgb(6, 137, 203)';
}).css('background-color', 'green');
```

Reference this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1740716/3046413)** if you decide to manually convert the hex value:

Comment: Sorry. Was a typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to match your hex color to color that computed style returns (which will not be hex) is to create an element...apply that color to it using hex, then see what browser returns as computed color

```js
function getComputedColorVal(hex) {
  return $('<span>').css('color', hex).css('color');
}

let hex = '#0689cb',
  computedColor = getComputedColorVal(hex)

$('*').filter(function() {
  return $(this).css('background-color') === computedColor;
}).css('background-color', 'green');
```

```css
.blue{background-color:#0689cb}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="blue">Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li class="blue">Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li class="blue">Item</li>
</ul>
```