# How to use javascript variable in css class name and get css color name through jquery in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

**Q1.**

I have a total of 7 divs (class name: scale-up-center0 ~ 7),
I want to represent numbers 1 through 7 using a javascript variable.

I tried the for statement, but it did not work.

I want scale-up-center7 to change color when scale-up-center0-6 is clicked.

How do I use a javascript variable for a css class name?

**not working code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        for(var i=0; i<7; i++) {
        $(".scale-up-center-<%=i%>").click(function() {
            var color = $(".scale-up-center-<%=i%>).css("background-color");
            $(".scale-up-center7").css("background-color", color);
            $("#post_color").val(color);
        }

    })
})
```

**Q2.**

I imported the css property (background-color) through jquery and stored it in the color column.

And displays the color through the input of the form. However, it is expressed in the form of rgb (255,0,0).

I have a color column in the DB, but it is a string type, and rgb () does not.

I want to import the color name rather than rgb. (ex) return "red", instead of rgb (255,0,0)

**_form.html.erb**

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :color %>
    <%= form.text_area :color, id: 'post_color' %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1.
Try to use `$(".scale-up-center-" + i)` instead of `$(".scale-up-center-<%=i%>")`

Q2.
Saving a color as CSS color name could be a little bit tricky.
I suggest you to convert RGB to HEX (this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value) could help) and convert it to color name with CSS colors list (e.g from here [css-color-names](https://github.com/bahamas10/css-color-names)).

Comment: thank you! However, if you type a direct value (".scale-up-center" + i) as var i = 2 ;, for (var i = 0; i <7; i ++) does not work.

Comment: Is it `(".scale-up-center" + i)` or `(".scale-up-center-" + i)`?

Comment: My class names consist of .scale-up-center0 ~ 7!
ex) <div class = "scale-up-center2">

And I used it.
(".scale-up-center" + i) ////

var i = 2;
$ (". scale-up-center2"). click ..... This works fine

It does not work when using the for statement using the variable i.

Comment: You mustn't change `i` value inside the cycle.
If you want to do something specific with the 2nd element better do something like:
`for(var i=0; i<7; i++) { if (i === 2) { do something } ... }`

Comment: Yes. I did a test on scale-up-center2. ////
for(var i=0; i<7; i++) { (i === 2) {code ... include $ (". scale-up-center" + i) .click (function () {... I used ... but it does not work.