# Update data using jquery, ajax, php, mysqli and bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli, bootstrap-4

First, sorry for the bad english but is not my native language.

The problem is that when i fill the fields for update a data, this can update on table or interface, but in mysql doesn't.

Furthermore, i have trouble with the color data type because this type can't pass like color, only pass like text type.

So, can you help me? Thanks.

I try to explain this for understand better the problem:
[This is the list of elements originals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4g0y.png)

Next, when i try to update:
[This is the camps that i want to update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQPDM.png)

Finally, update but only on table not mysql:
[Last step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5xlR.png)

Note: I know that the color give a text and not a color, but i can't found on the documentation how get a value like color type. help again?.

Now the code:
The first is a html archive that i need call always because have all the dependencies.
The name of the archive is : estandar.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the code interface of update data:

The name of the archive is: editar_linea.php
Note: coneccion.php is a archive that have the connection to database for select the data and display on a table.

```html
<?php
include('estandar.html');
include('coneccion.php');
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['correcto']==1){
 $contador = 0;
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Editar linea TransValparaiso</title>
  </head>

  <body class="bg-light">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-light sticky-top flex-md-nowrap p-0" style="background-color: #F38E0E">
      <a class="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0" href="transvalparaiso_ingreso_administrador_general2.php">Transporte<br>Metropolitano<br>Valparaiso</a>
    </nav>
      <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

<?php
//------------------------------------------------------------------BARRA DE OPCIONES--------------------------------------------------------------------------
include('barra_opciones_transvalparaiso.php');
//---------------------------------------------------------Editar LINEA-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
?>

        <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">
          <h2>Seleccione la línea que desea editar</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  
                  <th><nav class="navbar sticky top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">Nombre Linea</nav></th>
                  <th><nav class="navbar sticky top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">Rut Linea</nav></th>
                  <th><nav class="navbar sticky top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">Color Principal</nav></th>
                  <th><nav class="navbar sticky top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">Color Secundario</nav></th>
                  <th><nav class="navbar sticky top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">Acción</nav></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

              <?php
              $sql="SELECT * FROM `linea` WHERE 1";
              $resultado=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
              while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
               $contador=$contador+1;
              ?>

                <tr id ="<?php echo $row['id_linea']; ?>">
                  <td data-target = "nombre_linea"><?php echo $row['nombre_linea']; ?></td>
                  <td data-target = "rut_linea"><?php echo $row['rut_linea']; ?></td>
                  <td data-target = "color_principal_linea"><nav class="navbar sticky top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light" style="background-color:<?php echo $row['color_principal_linea']; ?>;"</nav></td>
                  <td data-target = "color_secundario_linea"><nav class="navbar sticky top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light" style="background-color:<?php echo $row['color_secundario_linea']; ?>;"</nav></td>
                  <td><a href = "#" data-role = "update" data-id ="<?php echo $row['id_linea']; ?>">Update</a></td>
                </tr>

              <?php
              }
              ?>

              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
                <!-- Modal -->
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Actualizar</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Nombre Linea</label>
                          <input type="text" id="nombre_linea" name ="nombre_linea" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Rut linea</label>
                          <input type="number" id="rut_linea" name = "rut_linea" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Color Principal</label>
                          <input type="color" id="color_principal1_linea" name = "color_principal1_linea" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Color Secundario</label>
                          <input type="color" id="color_secundario2_linea" name = color_secundario2_linea class="form-control">
                        </div>
                           <input type="hidden" id="userId" class="form-control">

                      </div>
                       <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#" id="save" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Update</a>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>

        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click','a[data-role=update]', function(){
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            var nombre_linea  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=nombre_linea]').text();
            var rut_linea  = parseInt($('#'+id).children('td[data-target=rut_linea]').text());
            var color_principal_linea  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=color_principal_linea]').html();
            var color_secundario_linea  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=color_secundario_linea]').html();

        $('#nombre_linea').val(nombre_linea);
        $('#rut_linea').val(rut_linea);
        $('#color_principal1_linea').val(color_principal_linea);
        $('#color_secundario2_linea').val(color_secundario_linea);
        $('#userId').val(id);
        $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
      });

       $('#save').click(function(){
          var id  = $('#userId').val(); 
         var nombre_linea =  $('#nombre_linea').val();
         var rut_linea =  $('#rut_linea').val();
         var color_principal_linea =  $('#color_principal1_linea').val();
          var color_secundario_linea =  $('#color_secundario2_linea').val();

          $.ajax({
              url      : 'connection.php',
              type   : 'POST', 
              data     : {nombre_linea : nombre_linea , rut_linea: rut_linea , color_principal_linea : color_principal_linea , color_secundario_linea : color_secundario_linea , id: id},
              success  : function(response){
                             $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=nombre_linea]').text(nombre_linea);
                             parseInt($('#'+id).children('td[data-target=rut_linea]').text(rut_linea));
                             $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=color_principal_linea]').text(color_principal_linea);
                             $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=color_secundario_linea]').text(color_secundario_linea);
                             $('#myModal').modal('toggle'); 
                         }
          });
       });
  });
  </script>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

This is coneccion.php:

```html
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$db = "transvalparaiso";
 
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db);
  
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}else {
 //echo "conecto correctamente";
}
?>
```

And the last code is for update on mysqli:

The name is: connection.php

```html
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost' , 'root' ,'' ,'transvalparaiso');

if(isset($_POST['id'])){
 
 $nombre_linea = $_POST['nombre_linea'];
 $rut_linea = $_POST['rut_linea'];
 $color_principal_linea = $_POST['color_principal_linea'];
 $color_secundario_linea = $_POST['color_secundario_linea'];
 $id_linea = $_POST['id'];
  
 $result  = mysqli_query($connection , "UPDATE linea SET nombre_linea='$nombre_linea' , color_principal_linea = '$color_principal_linea' , color_secundario_linea = '$color_secundario_linea' , rut_linea='$rut_linea' WHERE id='$id_linea'");

 if($result){
  echo 'data updated';
 }

}
?>
```

I follow this example for the code:
[Example for implement modal](https://youtu.be/aujNp92p0Uc)

Comment: What do you mean by "get a value like color type" ?

Comment: it's like: #00000 YES, "#00000" NOT. Sorry for my english men :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems you are facing when updating the colors are because of two things:

- You are targeting the wrong selector when retrieving the colors. There's a `nav` element that holds the color property.
- The color you get from the `nav` is in rgb, while `input[type=color]` seems to expect a hex value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hexDigits = new Array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");

  //Function to convert rgb color to hex format
  function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
  }

  function hex(x) {
    return isNaN(x) ? "00" : hexDigits[(x - x % 16) / 16] + hexDigits[x % 16];
  }

  $(document).on('click', 'a[data-role=update]', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var color_principal_linea = $('#' + id).children('td[data-target="color_principal_linea"]').children('nav').css('background-color');
    var color_secundario_linea = $('#' + id).children('td[data-target="color_secundario_linea"]').children('nav').css('background-color')

    $('#color_principal1_linea').val(rgb2hex(color_principal_linea));
    $('#color_secundario2_linea').val(rgb2hex(color_secundario_linea));
    $('#userId').val(id);
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
  });

  $('#save').click(function() {
    var id = $('#userId').val();
    var color_principal_linea = $('#color_principal1_linea').val();
    var color_secundario_linea = $('#color_secundario2_linea').val();
    $('#' + id).find('td[data-target="color_principal_linea"] nav').css('background-color', color_principal_linea);
    $('#' + id).find('td[data-target="color_secundario_linea"] nav').css('background-color', color_secundario_linea);
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">
    <h2>Seleccione la línea que desea editar</h2>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <nav class="navbar sticky top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">Color Principal</nav>
            </th>
            <th>
              <nav class="navbar sticky top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">Color Secundario</nav>
            </th>
            <th>
              <nav class="navbar sticky top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">Acción</nav>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr id="1">
            <td data-target="color_principal_linea">
              <nav class="navbar sticky top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light" style="background-color:#000fff" </nav>
            </td>
            <td data-target="color_secundario_linea">
              <nav class="navbar sticky top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light" style="background-color:#aaaa00" </nav>
            </td>
            <td><a href="#" data-role="update" data-id="1">Update</a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="2">
            <td data-target="color_principal_linea">
              <nav class="navbar sticky top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light" style="background-color: #a00fff;" </nav>
            </td>
            <td data-target="color_secundario_linea">
              <nav class="navbar sticky top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light" style="background-color: #aafa00" </nav>
            </td>
            <td><a href="#" data-role="update" data-id="2">Update</a></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Actualizar</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Color Principal</label>
              <input type="color" id="color_principal1_linea" name="color_principal1_linea" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Color Secundario</label>
              <input type="color" id="color_secundario2_linea" name="color_secundario2_linea" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" id="userId" class="form-control">

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" id="save" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Update</a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The php updating function isn't returning anything, so your `success` callback is just setting the same values that you sent to the server and you don't really need to do it (unless you want to revert it, but to do that you have to capture the original state first). You can use a `error` callback instead to alert the user that the update failed.

Reference: [How to convert rgb to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700)

Comment: I agree with you, the #userId value that you get from the bootstrap modal is not receiving the corresponding id, even though in the previous function you specify that the current id is assigned #userId.
Try using your proposed solutions, however, I did not succeed. Thank you very much anyway.
I had used CSS before but I was not able to recognize that the variable was a color, on the other hand, if I use the back-ground color it is able to recognize it after the update of the data, but not when I call them by the link update and open the modal form for the first time for that record.

Answer (score 0):

now edit on bbdd.

The error was on this line:

```html
$result  = mysqli_query($connection , "UPDATE linea SET nombre_linea='$nombre_linea' , color_principal_linea = '$color_principal_linea' , color_secundario_linea = '$color_secundario_linea' , rut_linea='$rut_linea' WHERE id='$id_linea'");
```

this is the correct:

```html
$result  = mysqli_query($connection , "UPDATE linea SET nombre_linea='$nombre_linea' , color_principal_linea = '$color_principal_linea' , color_secundario_linea = '$color_secundario_linea' , rut_linea='$rut_linea' WHERE id_linea='$id_linea'");
```

Note: I have one solution, but I still can not place the color variable after the update, that is, if I refresh the page the changes are seen, but when I clicked on the update, I did not