# Get color of DIV in hex format JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my code:

```
function getTraits(trait) {
    $("#"+trait).on("click", function() {
        alert($(this).css('backgroundColor'));
        if (toHex($(this).css('background-color')) != highlightedColor) {
            $("#"+trait).css("background-color", highlightedColor);
            // If the element isn't highlighted, highlight it.
        } else {
            $(this).css("backgroundColor", defaultColor);
        }
    })
}
```

I am trying to toggle a highlight on a div on the user's click. I would like to get the background color of the div because it would be inefficient to store a boolean toggle for each and every div. So I want a `toHex(rgb)` function. I saw a lot of those on SO, so I tried  using them and none of them worked. The `alert()` I put to show me the format JQuery was returning gave me `rgba(0,0,0,0)`. I attempted to modify a regex I found like this:

`var rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+))$/);`

That failed to work with a TypeError: `rgb is null`.

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: What is `rgb` variable?

Comment: You may want to consider using a CSS class to toggle the background color instead.

Comment: @FZs Sorry, I made a typo. `var rgb = rgb ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know, not the answer to your question, but have you considered jQuery's `toggleClass()` option?

Define a `highlighted` CSS class:

```
DIV.default { background-color: whitesmoke; }
DIV.highlighted { background-color: yellow; }
```

and then when the user clicks your DIV:

```
function getTraits(trait) {
    $("#"+trait).on("click", function() {
        // Toggle both classes so as to turn one "off" 
        // and the other "on"
        $(this).toggleClass('default');
        $(this).toggleClass('highlighted');

        // Ensure we have at least one class (default)
        var hasOne = $(this).hasClass('highlighted') || $(this).hasClass('default');
        if (!hasOne) {
          $(this).addClass('default');
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: This works very well, but could you put in a way to do it without `!important`? In my experience, my code gets impossible to read when I put too many `!important`s in.

Comment: Sure thing - we now toggle both classes and check to make sure the DIV has at least one class should some state arise where both classes get toggled OFF.

Answer (score 3):

First of all get Background-Color and use the below function to convert it into HEX Value

```
var rgb=$(selector).css('background-color');
var hexColor=rgb2hex(rgb);

function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?[\s+]?\([\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?/i);
    return (rgb && rgb.length === 4) ? "#" +
        ("0" + parseInt(rgb[1], 10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
        ("0" + parseInt(rgb[2], 10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
        ("0" + parseInt(rgb[3], 10).toString(16)).slice(-2) : '';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Your problem:** jquery will return `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` if there is no background color set (i.e. it is `undefinied` / `null`). The problem you have is that you are trying to parse an undefined rgb string into the hex converter.

I've added a clause into the converted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value#answer-3627747), so that it returns white if the value is unset but this would need uncommenting, and isn't advised.

**Advised solution** is to use toggleClass, see the demo further down, showing how you can toggle higlighting on indiviidual elements or entire DOM trees.

---

## Demo of rgb issue

```js
// Cycle through each div
$("#example-wrap div").each(function() {

  // Store rgb color
  var rgb = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
  
  // Print rgb color to the div
  $(this).append( ": " + rgb);

  // Append the hex value
  $(this).append(" -> " + rgb2hex(rgb));
  
});


function rgb2hex(rgb) {
  rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);

  function hex(x) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }
  
  // Check if rgb is null
  if (rgb == null ) {
    // You could repalce the return with a default color, i.e. the line below
    // return "#ffffff"
    return "Error";
  }

  return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
  
}
```

```css
#example-wrap div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  color: black;
}

#example-wrap .background-blue {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

#example-wrap .background-white {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-wrap">

  <div id="background-set" style="background-color: red; color: white;">Background set in 'style' attribute</div>

  <div id="background-class" class="background-blue">Background set to blue via class</div>

  <div id="background-class" class="background-white">Background set to white via class</div>

  <div id="background-none">No background set</div>

</div>
```

---

## Highlight via Toggle Class

This example lets you highlight individual elements tagged with `.highlightable`, as well as applying wrappers which mean all their children are highlightable via the class `.highlightable-wrapper`.

```js
// Add click event to highlightable elements and wrappers
$(document).on("click", ".highlightable, .highlightable-wrapper *", function(e) {

  // Toggle highlight class
  $(this).toggleClass("highlight-me");
  
  // Stop click event from propogating (i.e. allow spans to be highlighted individually)
  // Uncomment this if you want propogation
  e.stopPropagation()

});
```

```css
.highlight-me {
  color: blue;
}

.highlightable-wrapper .highlight-me, .highlightable-wrapper .highlight-me * {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="example-wrapper">

  <div class="highlightable">
    <h4>Individual Element Example</h4>
    This is an exampled of a div with the .highlightable class.
  </div>

  <hr style="margin: 20px 0px;">

  <div class="highlightable-wrapper">
  
    <h4>Wrapper Example</h4>
    
    <p>I am a paragraph within an element with the .highlightable-wrapper class.</p>
    
    <p>Click us to see us change <strong>I am a strong span, you can individually highlight me</strong>.</p>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```