# Is there a reason why Javascript's "document.querySelector().style.backgroundColor" converts HEX to RGB?

Tags: javascript, html, methods, hex, rgb

This is my first question on here, please be gentle. I just noticed in Safari, Chrome and Firefox's console, the color values from the following script always return an RGB value instead of a HEX value. Not that it's preventing the code from working or anything, I'm just curious to know why wouldn't the console return the HEX value that was sent? Does Javascript always translate color values to RGB? Is it a first class citizen over other paradigms?

```
function randomHEX() {
    var HEXvalues = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];
    var newHEX = "#";

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        var nextIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * HEXvalues.length); // grab a random value from the array
        newHEX += HEXvalues[nextIndex]; // increment values to newHEX
    }

    document.querySelector("#hexName").textContent = newHEX; // use newHEX to fill text of ID hexName
    document.querySelector(".container").style.backgroundColor = newHEX; // use newHEX to change background color of box
}
```

[Safari console window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s18O7.jpg)

Any information would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

---

PS

Thank you to those who responded. My question though was *why* RGB? *Why* not default to the HEX number it received? *Why* does Javascript translate a HEX value to an RGB value with .style.backgroundColor?

Again, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes by default it is displayed as RGB. To convert it to HEX, it has been already answered here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value)

Answer (score 0):

This is not your issue. Your function makes HEX value correctly. You can check it by adding `console.log(newHEX)` at the end of your function.

`element.style.color = HEX_string` it will be converted into RGB value.

If you need to convert it back - check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb).