# How to return hexcode value of the background color of a div(without jquery)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose I have a div like this

```
<div style="height:50px; width:50px; background-color:#ffffff" id="a1"></div>
```

What will I do in JS to get `#ffffff` in a string?

Comment: You can't obtain it easy way. Javascript style property will return rgb in most cases.
I found exact same question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1740716/6730646
i assume you will also find some proper explanation here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the browser being used, colors being retrieved from DOM elements will return as RGB values unless specified directly with Javascript.

For instance, using your example code, we can apply the `div` background color with JS like this:

```
//get the div by id
var div = document.getElementById('a1');
//apply divs background color
var divBgColor = div.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
```

If you `console.log(divBgColor);` after specifying the background color with the code above, it will return a Hexadecimal value `#ffffff` as you expect.

However, if the background color is already declared in your element and you want to retrieve it, you will have to do a bit more.

Again, using your example we can get the background color like this:

```
var divBgColor = document.getElementById('a1').style.backgroundColor;
```

If you `console.log(divBgColor);` now, it will return a string `rgb(255, 255, 255)`, however, since you are looking for the Hexadecimal value we can run a function to convert the RGB value to Hexadecimal.

```
    function convertRgb(rgb) {
  // This will choose the correct separator, if there is a "," in your value it will use a comma, otherwise, a separator will not be used.
  var separator = rgb.indexOf(",") > -1 ? "," : " ";


  // This will convert "rgb(r,g,b)" into [r,g,b] so we can use the "+" to convert them back to numbers before using toString 
  rgb = rgb.substr(4).split(")")[0].split(separator);

  // Here we will convert the decimal values to hexadecimal using toString(16)
  var r = (+rgb[0]).toString(16),
    g = (+rgb[1]).toString(16),
    b = (+rgb[2]).toString(16);

  if (r.length == 1)
    r = "0" + r;
  if (g.length == 1)
    g = "0" + g;
  if (b.length == 1)
    b = "0" + b;

  // The return value is a concatenation of "#" plus the rgb values which will give you your hex
  return "#" + r + g + b;
}
```

Now you can call the function with your `divBgColor` like this, `convertRgb(divBgColor)` and it will output your Hexadecimal value.

Run the snippet below to see it in action.

```js
var divBgColor = document.getElementById('a1').style.backgroundColor;

function convertRgb(rgb) {
  // This will choose the correct separator, if there is a "," in your value it will use a comma, otherwise, a separator will not be used.
  var separator = rgb.indexOf(",") > -1 ? "," : " ";


  // This will convert "rgb(r,g,b)" into [r,g,b] so we can use the "+" to convert them back to numbers before using toString 
  rgb = rgb.substr(4).split(")")[0].split(separator);

  // Here we will convert the decimal values to hexadecimal using toString(16)
  var r = (+rgb[0]).toString(16),
    g = (+rgb[1]).toString(16),
    b = (+rgb[2]).toString(16);

  if (r.length == 1)
    r = "0" + r;
  if (g.length == 1)
    g = "0" + g;
  if (b.length == 1)
    b = "0" + b;

  // The return value is a concatenation of "#" plus the rgb values which will give you your hex
  return "#" + r + g + b;
}

console.log(convertRgb(divBgColor))
```

```html
<div style="height:50px; width:50px; background-color:#ffffff" id="a1"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

`document.querySelector('.yourDiv').style.backgroundColor`

Comment: then just convert the rgb to hex yourself